# Plastic SCM migration & configuration guide? to migrate to new machine?

Tags: migration, plasticscm

Plastic SCM migration & configuration guide? to migrate to new machine?

If it exists please dont give me negative a my googling and searching did not come up with a GUIDE. I looked around could not find anything definitive.

Please link me to it or share a definitive set of steps/ guide and what/ how to be backed up/ restored for migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I properly understand, you need to migrate a Plastic SCM server to a new machine. For that purpose:

- Install the last Plastic SCM version in your new machine.
- Migrate the databases: The goal is to move the databases to the new server location. You can directly copy the database files to the new location or even run a replica operation between the two servers.
- Copy the next configuration files in order to keep your server configuration parameters:
- *db.conf* -> Is the one handling the database connection.
- *users.conf* and groups.conf -> If you are using the User&Password authentication mode.
- *plasticd.lic* -> The license file.
- *server.conf* -> Your old server configuration parameters.

PD: Remember also to reconfigure your clients to point to the new server location. You will probably have workspaces with selector pointing to the old server.